# Creating elements with .map() - DOM builds it with comas

Tags: javascript

Working with .map() I've faced with a strange behaviour: the complete DOM renders my elements with comas. Can't understand where they come from. Any clues?
http://prntscr.com/fly356

```js
function portfolio() {
        let portfolio = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-content')[0];
        let list = [
            {link: "/img/img1.png", title: "Printed swimsuit", price: "23", filter: ['all', 'sweaters', 'jacket']},
            {link: "/img/img2.png", title: "Jogging bermuda shorts", price_new: "12", price_old: "36", filter: ['all', 'shorts']},
            {link: "/img/img3.png", title: "Basic beach flip flops", price: "9", new_product: true, filter: ['all', 'accessories']},
            {link: "/img/img4.png", title: "Black sunglasses", price: "29", filter: ['all', 'accessories']}
           
        ]

        let navigation = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-navigation li');
        Array.from(navigation).forEach( (el) => {
            el.addEventListener('click', () => {

                let port_el = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-content_element');

                for(let val of navigation) {
                    if(val.classList.contains('active')) {
                         val.classList.remove('active');
                    }
                    port_el.forEach(item => {
                        if(!item.classList.contains(el.innerText.toLowerCase())) {
                            item.style.display = 'none'
                        } else {
                            item.style.display = 'initial'
                        }
                    })

                    el.classList.add('active');
                }
            })
        })
        const complete_list = list.map((element) => {
            let {link, title, price, price_new, price_old, new_product, filter} = element;
            let portfolio_element;
            let product_state;           

            if (typeof new_product != 'undefined' && new_product === true) {
                    product_state = "new ";
            } else {
                    product_state = "";
            }
            if (typeof price != 'undefined') {
                return `<div class="portfolio-content_element ${product_state}">
                                <img src="${link}">
                                <div class="title">${title}</div>
                                <div class="price">
                                    <span class="currency">$</span>${price}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        `
            } else {
                return `
                            <div class="portfolio-content_element ${product_state}">
                                <img src="${link}">
                                <div class="title">${title}</div>
                                <span class="price price-old">
                                    <span class="currency">$</span>${price_old}
                                </span>
                                <span class="price price-new">
                                    <span class="currency">$</span>${price_new}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        `
            }
        })
        portfolio.innerHTML = complete_list
    }
portfolio()
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">                        
 <div class="portfolio-content"></div>
</div>
```

Also the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/owWNzz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are assigning `complete_list` which is an array to `innerHTML` property, it is internally converted using `.toString()` thus commas are getting appended.

*Use*

```
portfolio.innerHTML = complete_list.join('');
```

instead of

```
portfolio.innerHTML = complete_list;
```

```js
function portfolio() {
  let portfolio = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-content')[0];
  let list = [{
      link: "/img/img1.png",
      title: "Printed swimsuit",
      price: "23",
      filter: ['all', 'sweaters', 'jacket']
    },
    {
      link: "/img/img2.png",
      title: "Jogging bermuda shorts",
      price_new: "12",
      price_old: "36",
      filter: ['all', 'shorts']
    },
    {
      link: "/img/img3.png",
      title: "Basic beach flip flops",
      price: "9",
      new_product: true,
      filter: ['all', 'accessories']
    },
    {
      link: "/img/img4.png",
      title: "Black sunglasses",
      price: "29",
      filter: ['all', 'accessories']
    }

  ]

  let navigation = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-navigation li');
  Array.from(navigation).forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {

      let port_el = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-content_element');

      for (let val of navigation) {
        if (val.classList.contains('active')) {
          val.classList.remove('active');
        }
        port_el.forEach(item => {
          if (!item.classList.contains(el.innerText.toLowerCase())) {
            item.style.display = 'none'
          } else {
            item.style.display = 'initial'
          }
        })

        el.classList.add('active');
      }
    })
  })
  const complete_list = list.map((element) => {
    let {
      link,
      title,
      price,
      price_new,
      price_old,
      new_product,
      filter
    } = element;
    let portfolio_element;
    let product_state;

    if (typeof new_product != 'undefined' && new_product === true) {
      product_state = "new ";
    } else {
      product_state = "";
    }
    if (typeof price != 'undefined') {
      return `<div class="portfolio-content_element ${product_state}">
                                <img src="${link}">
                                <div class="title">${title}</div>
                                <div class="price">
                                    <span class="currency">$</span>${price}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        `
    } else {
      return `
                            <div class="portfolio-content_element ${product_state}">
                                <img src="${link}">
                                <div class="title">${title}</div>
                                <span class="price price-old">
                                    <span class="currency">$</span>${price_old}
                                </span>
                                <span class="price price-new">
                                    <span class="currency">$</span>${price_new}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        `
    }
  })
  portfolio.innerHTML = complete_list.join('')
}
portfolio()
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="portfolio-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: IMHO right way would be to [create document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

Answer (score 1):

```
portfolio.innerHTML = complete_list.join('').replace(/,/g, '');
```

The problem here is when you run .map, it will always give you the output an array. In your case, we join the array first and then, remove all the commas. NOTE: this will remove all commas from the list. (Handles the current scenario)

If you wanted to do it via some other way, you should have run a simple for loop `for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)` and then, taken a `var output=''` and concatenate the constructed string at the end of the loop.